# Symbolically add another variable to LSTM kernel in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to understand if it is feasible in TF 2.0 to symbolically add to the weight variable of LSTM (self.kernel) another tf.Variable which I will control during training (it can be non-trainable itself).

E.g:

```
    class AwesomeLSTM(tf.keras.layers.LSTM)

        def build(...)
            super().build(...)
            self.new_weight = self.add_weight(shape=self.kernel.shape, ...)
            self.kernel = self.kernel + self.new_weight
```

but when I change self.new_weight the value of self.kernel is not changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue in a project of mine (not on a LSTM though).
From what I could tell the problem is that when `model.build()` is called, the numpy value of `self.new_weight` is taken, not the symbolic variable.

A workaround that worked for me is adding the new_weight in the call function. In this case you need a different kernel so the addition doesn't aggregate:

```
class my_LSTM(tf.keras.layers.LSTM):
    def build(self,input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)
        self.new_weight = self.add_weight(shape=self.kernel.shape,trainable=False)
        self.actual_kernel = self.add_weight(shape=self.kernel.shape,trainable=True)

    def call(self,inputs,*args):
        self.kernel = self.actual_kernel+self.new_weight
        super().call(inputs,*args)
```

When testing this you need to keep in mind that the `layer.kernel` doesn't change until the layer is called again.

Hope this helps, when someone finds a way to do it symbolically as you probably intended I would also be very interested.

Comment: That seem to work, but it looks like it can use additional memory and things that worked fine without it started triggering OOM :(

Comment: you could try what happens if you don't the kernel build as a trainable variable from the beginning, so, add `del self.kernel` or similar in the build function that the optimizer doesn't try to compute gradients for the kernel